# hi ! rinkeby faucet is not working for me . can you send me some eth to 0x795641a8dCc6CF13369abd6E177D64C8956dDe9A

Tags: ether, rinkeby, faucets

rinkeby faucet is not working .some rinkeby eth required please

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if [this faucet](https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby) helps you.

p.s. sent you 01 ETH ([txn hash](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xa5e596f10cb4d46f76aff59ef9d20e6c1a6d4e7f1b6d8f17d99a363e15f1cbcd))